# Need a SQL query to find the best possible answers based on letter differences

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, substring, letter

I have 2 tables, table A and Table B.

Table A contains 2 sessions. the guesses column are guesses, and the correct letter in correct position column tells as the name suggest which letters in the guesses were in the correct position. Each session has 1 correct answer,

```
  Table A

   Session       Guesses     Correct_letter_in_correct_position     Correct letter_in_wrong_position
      1             ABDC                    2                                        2
      1             ABCF                    3                                        0
      1             BAFD                    1                                        2
      2             EFGD                    3                                        0
      2             EFHG                    2                                        2
      2             EFGI                    3                                        0
```

Table B contains all possible answers including the right answer and wrong answers
For example:

```
Table B

Possible_answers
    ABCD
    PQRS
    BCDA
    RSTU
    ..
    ..`etc
```

`

I need a Query/logic in SQL to get the best possible answer based on Table A and Table B in such way the query gives an output like this which shows the exact right answers

```
Session   Best_possible_answer
   1             ABCD 
   2             EFGH
```

or like this which shows all the possible answers that could be possible

```
Session     Best_possible_answer
   1                ABCD
   1                BACD
   1                ..
   2                EFGH
   2                EFGJ
   2                EFGK
```

NOTE: The best possible answers should come from Table B

Comment: I don't understand what you need table B for. It looks like you just want the guesses from table A that have the best match in a session (max of correct position + incorrect position, then max of correct position in case of a tie). Am I wrong?

Comment: And please tell us what DBMS you are using. Even better would be to know the DBMS and the version :-) SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS, because answers can vary extremely depending on this.

Comment: No the guesses from table A are incorrect but gives a hint on how close the letters should be. Using this , I need to find the best possible guess from Table B to show in the output

Comment: postgresql @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Okay. This looks much like the master mind game. Solving such a puzzle is nothing I'd do in SQL. This might be solvable with a cross join and then weighing the answers by position matches and letter matches somehow. Don't know, maybe not. If it were, then SQL could be fine for this. but the needed process is much more likely an iterative one. Iterations in SQL are done with recursive queries, but a programming language should be the better tool here.

Comment: Anyway, every programming task has two steps (at least): 1. Find the algorithm, 2. convert this into code. Have you done part 1 yet? Then we could tell you, whether SQL is appropriate for this.